# Let $T$ be the linear operator on $M_{n}(\textbf{R})$ defined by $T(A) = A^{t}$. Find a basis $\mathcal{B}$ s.t. $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

Let $T$ be the linear operator on $M_{n\times n}(\textbf{R})$ defined by $T(A) = A^{t}$.

(a) Show that $\pm 1$ are the only eigenvalues of $T$.

(b) Describe the eigenvectors corresponding to each eigenvalue of $T$.

(c) Find an ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $M_{2\times 2}(\textbf{R})$ such that $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is a diagonal matrix.

(d) Find an ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $M_{n\times n}(\textbf{R})$ such that $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is a diagonal matrix for $n > 2$.

**MY (NEW) ATTEMPT**

(a) Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\textbf{R})$ s.t. $A
\neq 0$. Then $A$ is an eigenvector of $T$ iff $T(A) = \lambda A$, that is to say, $A^{t} = \lambda A$.

Based on it, we conclude that $A = \lambda A^{t}$. Finally, one has that
\begin{align*}
A^{t} = \lambda(\lambda A^{t}) \Rightarrow A^{t} = \lambda^{2}A^{t} \Rightarrow \det(A^{t}) = \lambda^{2n}\det(A^{t}) \Rightarrow \lambda^{2n} = 1 \Rightarrow \lambda = \pm 1
\end{align*}

But I still do not know how to justify the implication where we consider $\det(A^{t}) \neq 0$

Any help in this sense is appreciated.

(b) For $\lambda = 1$, we have that $T(A) = A^{t} = A$.

Thus the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 1$ belongs to the subspace of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

For $\lambda = -1$, we have that $T(A) = A^{t} = -A$.

Thus the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = -1$ belongs to the subspace of skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

(c) Let us determine the eigenspace associated to each eigenvalue. We shall start with $\lambda =1$:
\begin{align*}
T(A) = 1\cdot A \Rightarrow A^{t} = A \Rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow b = c
\end{align*}

Thus the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ is spanned by
\begin{align*}
E_{1} = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}
\end{align*}

We may now proceed and determine the eigenspace associated to $\lambda = -1$:
\begin{align*}
T(A) = -1\cdot A \Rightarrow A^{t} = -A \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-a & -b\\
-c & -d
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow b = -c,\,a = 0,\,d = 0.
\end{align*}

Thus the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$ is spanned by
\begin{align*}
E_{-1} = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}
\end{align*}

Since $E_{1}\cup E_{-1}$ is LI and it spans $M_{2\times 2}(\textbf{R})$, we conclude that $\mathcal{B} = E_{1}\cup E_{-1}$ is a basis indeed.

(d) The same reasoning applies to this case. Precisely speaking, there are $\displaystyle\dim\text{span}\{E_{1}\} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ symmetric matrices and $\displaystyle\dim\text{span}\{E_{-1}\} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$
skew-symmetric matrices in the corresponding bases.

**COMMENT**

This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632157/find-an-ordered-basis-mathcalb-for-m-2-times-2-textbfr-such-that), but I'd like to know if my new approach is fine. Any comments on the wording of my solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $A^t=\lambda A$ you can deduce $\lambda=1$ provided $A$ has a nonzero diagonal entry. But there can be eigenvectors that have zero along the diagonal and you would need to consider other cases.

There's a simpler way: every matrix $A$ can be uniquely written as the sum of a symmetric and an antisymmetric matrix: $A=A_++A_-$, where
$$
A_+=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t),\qquad A_-=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t)
$$
Then $A^t=A_+-A_-$ and from $A^t=\lambda A$ we get
$$
A_+ - A_-=\lambda A_+ + \lambda A_-
$$
By uniqueness, we obtain that $A_+=\lambda A_+$ and $-A_-=\lambda A_-$. Since $A\ne0$ (being an eigenvector), we see that either $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$ and, moreover, that an eigenvector is either a symmetric matrix (for the eigenvalue $1$) or an antisymmetric matrix (for the eigenvalue $-1$). Conversely, any (nonzero) symmetric matrix is an eigenvector for $1$ and any (nonzero) antisymmetric matrix is an eigenvector for $-1$.

Since the sum of the eigenspaces is $M_n(\mathbf{R})$, the endomorphism $T$ is diagonalizable and a basis of eigenvectors can be obtained by a basis of the symmetric matrices, with dimension $n(n+1)/2$, and of the antisymmetric matrices, with dimension $n(n-1)/2$. In the case $n=2$ a basis is
$$
\biggl\{
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\biggr\}
$$

---

About your attempt: $\lambda^{2n}=1$ doesn't imply by itself that $\lambda=\pm1$. You need to exclude complex eigenvalues and the fact you're working with real matrices is not relevant: the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
has real entries, but no real eigenvalue. On the other hand, for its eigenvalues $\lambda$ it is true that $\lambda^4=1$. Of course it's a different situation than yours, but it shows you have to be careful when jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems with your new attempt:

- It is not true that $\lambda^{2n} = 1$ implies that $\lambda = \pm 1$. Remember that we also need to rule out the possibility of complex eigenvalues.
- For $\lambda = -1$ (part c), you should have reached the conclusion
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  T(A) &= -1\cdot A \Rightarrow A^{t} = -A \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
  a & c\\
  b & d
  \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  -a & -b\\
  -c & -d
  \end{bmatrix} \\
  &\implies b = -c, \quad a= 0, \quad d = 0,
  \end{align*}
  $$
  which is what allows you to conclude that the eigenspace is indeed one-dimensional.

Otherwise, it seems fine as far as I could tell.